# How to fresh Redshift dev/qa enviroment from production

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, data-warehouse

We have Redshift as our data warehouse, and we have different environment such as production, QA(stage) and dev. It becomes really hard to perform testing and development on QA and dev because of missing data or schema changes made directly on production. 
I would like to know if there is a way to fresh dev/qa on schedule/on-demand from production on Redshift, appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"schema changes made directly on production" - I think you need to get this sorted out first! That really undermines the purpose of dev and QA environments if this is happening.

If you simply want a copy of production then you can use [cluster snapshots](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/working-with-snapshots.html) to back up the production cluster and restore a copy as a new dev or QA cluster.